# Tiny Death Star Decoration Event (March 2014)

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

So far I've only gotten a total of 8 decoration droids over the entire event.  Was just wondering if anyone else has had more luck getting them or not.

Comment: Your question is being voted down because this isn't a question so much as a complaint. A more neutral phrasing might be "What is the probability of receiving a Decorator Droid when the elevator is populated?" This site is meant to be for questions and answers, not general forums (though you're welcome to leave relevant comments on other questions or answers).

Answer (score 1):

They are rare; on the Christmas event for example, there were much easier to find. I've gotten about 18 or so, and summoned enough to complete the event with Bux. I recommend that you do the same thing, because at the very low rate they appear, you won't be able to finish the event in time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 1% chance of receiving a Decorator Droid.

I kept track of 400 bitizens coming to the elevator, and in that time, I received exactly 4 Decorator Droids.

Of the 400 bitizens:

305 (~76%) were regular bitizens
67 (~17%) were "?" bitizens
4 (1%) were Level Mover VIP
3 (.75%) were Big Spender VIP
4 (1%) were Recruiter VIP
5 (1.25%) were Level Upgrader VIP
4 (1%) were Celebrity VIP
4 (1%) were Supply Officer VIP
4 (1%) were Decorator Droid Special Event

Clearly the game thinks of the Decorator Droid as just another VIP, of which each one has a 1% chance of appearing.

That means that in order to obtain all of the prizes from the event without using any bux, you'd need to deliver 6,000 bitizens, or 600/day for the duration of the contest.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten about 8 free ones as well... The rest, I bought with bux. I've bought abt 42 and intend to buy the last 10 for the Overbridge level, but I will wait until the last day to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I've received one decorate droid each day, I've bought all the decorator droids needed to complete the event and still, no imperial missions.
I suggest that you buy the droids you can because time is running out.